# Buttons not joining in Bootstrap Button Groups

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, buttongroup

[image]
This is very bizarre and must be something silly. This works fine...

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" id="lead_buttons">
                  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default lead" id="lead_0">All</a>
                  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default lead" id="lead_1">Lead</a>
                </div>
```

... but when I change class="btn-group" to class="btn-group-sm" the buttons aren't joined anymore. They are separate.

Comment: Have you tried combining them? `class="btn-group btn-group-sm"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should work.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" id="lead_buttons">
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default lead" id="lead_0">All</a>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default lead" id="lead_1">Lead</a>
</div>
```

You need to add `btn-group btn-group-sm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs">All</a>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Lead</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

You can also try this